# What is the extra call mscorlib.ni when working with tasks?

Tags: .net, performance, debugging, async-await, task

This is my test code

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 1000 * 1000 * 1000; i++)
            {
                if (i%1000 == 0)
                {
                    var someIntTask = GetTaskInt(i);
                    var someInt = UnwrapResult(someIntTask);
                }
            }
        }

        private static int UnwrapResult(Task<int> someIntTask)
        {
            return someIntTask.Result;
        }

        static Task<int> GetTaskInt(int seed)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(seed + 10);
        }
    }
```

It's very straightforward. When I use VS2015 profiler, the result looks like this:

[image]

There is some call to mscorlib.ni.dll. Note that the task the code works with task only in condition `i%1000 == 0`.

When I use condition `i%10 == 0`, the result changes like this:

[image]

This means, that the extra call is somehow related to tasks, because time spent in it is in relation with time spent on working with tasks.

What is being done in the background in mscorlib.ni.dll?

Comment: It's just the native image of mscorlib then...almost anything Task.FromResult() does internally

Comment: There must be some code executed, right? So I'd like to know what code it is and why this is not counted to either method `UnwrapResult` or `GetTaskInt`. It looks like magic..

Comment: There will always be calls into mscorlib, it is where the Task class lives.  You just can't see the name of it because you don't have a PDB file for it.  Nor does it matter at all, focus on profiling your own code since that is the only code you can change to make your program faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ngened images don't have PDB files associated with them, which is why the profiler can't figure out which method from mscorlib is being called. But [you can create those PDBs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/12/10/creating-ngen-pdbs-for-profiling-reports/).

Without generating the PDB, I get results similar to yours:

[image]

After generating the PDB and reloading the report, I get:

[image]

This shows that most of the time spent inside mscorlib is from `Task.FromResult()`, which I think is not surprising.

Note that I get these results only when I profile in Debug mode, which you should never do. In Release mode, the results are quite different:

[image]